# RowEditEnding event for DataGridTemplateColumn is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, wpfdatagrid

I have following wpf grid i want to call RowEditEnding  event when user change event is not working for `DataGridTemplateColumn` .
 `DataGridTemplateColumn` excute only when i change values in `datagrid` defined controls like `DataGridTextColumn`,`DataGridComboBoxColumn`,etc

```
   <DataGrid Name="DriversDataGrid" Width="360" ItemsSource="{Binding GetAll}" CommandManager.PreviewExecuted="DriversDataGrid_PreviewDeleteCommandHandler" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowEditEnding="DataGrid_RowEditEnding">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Latest Victory Date" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding LatestVictory, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderThickness="0></DatePicker>
              </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn >
     </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

here is my event code

```
  private void DataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
            {

                FormulaOneDriver driver = e.Row.DataContext as FormulaOneDriver;
                MessageBox.Show("test");
                driver.Save();

            }
        }
```

**How to call `RowEditEnding` event for data in change in `DataGridTemplateColumn`  elements.**

Comment: You cannot call an event. Event is raised when something happens. RowEditEnding event is raised by DataGrid when you start editing some column and get out of that Row completely. What else you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: when in edit and get out of row  RowEditEnding event is not working when i exit only date field

Comment: Event will be fired when get out of that complete row and not just one field. Keep pressing tab and see when you enter first col of next row.

Comment: yes i am getting out of complete row

Comment: I have checked with DatePicker too, REE event is firing properly. This event is fired when you first enter in edit mode in any cell and then get out of that row completely. So, check if you are really entering in edit mode ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a CellEditingTemplate. This requires the user to click twice - once to select the cell and again to go into CellEditing mode

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Latest Victory Date" SortMemberPath="LatestVictory">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LatestVictory, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding LatestVictory, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ConverterCulture='en-GB', StringFormat=d}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```